# Adding annotation to test methods

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, annotations

I'm not sure 'annotations' is the current term, I'll try to explain by example:

```
    [MyAnnotation]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test123()
    {
        ...
    }
```

I want to define 'MyAnnotation' to affect the method in some way. Is that possible?
Couldn't find useful information about it. Thanks.

Comment: "*to affect the method in some way*" - what are you exactly trying to do

Comment: Let's say that I want it to be executed 2 times for start.

Comment: That's going to depend heavily on which unit testing framework you're using.

Comment: And how badly you want this feature and how much you want to fork the code

Comment: I'm using MSTest.

Answer (score 0):

"Annotations" (as they are called in Java) are called "Attributes" in C#.

You can easily define your own attributes. But they are not doing anything by their own. Attributes are only meta data. You need additional code to act on them. E.g. you could write a parser that detects them on runtime.

For running a test twice if it has your attribute attached, you would either need to write your own test-runner or extend the one you are currently using. Maybe there are even test-runners out there that are extensible in such a way. No matter what, nothing is going to happen at runtime, just because you attached a new attribute to a class or method.